# Can't load react-native app with expo app on the cellphone

Tags: react-native, npm, expo

I have created a React Native app with the npm package bootstrapper, then run the npm start command and everything seems to be right until then.

Now, when I go to the expo app on my cell phone and scan the QR code I always get this message "Something went wrong. Could not load exp://... . Network response timed out".

I'm on windows 10, and both the laptop and the cellphone are on the same wireless network.
I don't know what could be the problem, I followed the tutorial on this link:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html#content

I hope anyone can help me.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the offline option:

`exp start --offline`